# How to unify weights in my dataset

Tags: dataset, graphs, tfidf, knowledge-base, knowledge-graph

I have a symptom-disease network that consists of four attributes: symptom, disease,
co-occurrence and TF-IDF.
I'm considering the TF-IDF attribute as the weight of my network edges and symptom and disease attributes as nodes of my network. But I think there is a problem that should be addressed. here are some records of my dataset:

```
MeSH Symptom Term   MeSH Disease Term   PubMed occurrence   TFIDF score
"Aging, Premature"  Scoliosis           1                   3.46455149
"Aging, Premature"  HIV Infections      3                   10.39365447
Weight Loss         Scoliosis           1                   1.000053711
Overweight          Scoliosis           1                   0.8238721
```

As you can see for the disease "Scoliosis", for the same co-occurrence we have different TF-IDF scores for different symptoms.
Now the question is can I use these TF-IDF scores as weights directly or should I do some unification of weights? Thanks

Comment: On which column TF-IDF is being calculated?

Comment: This is how tf-idf is being calculated: we do not use the absolute co-occurrence Wi,j to measure the strength of an association between symptom i and disease j, but the term frequency-inverse document frequency wi,j:
wi,j= Wi,j * logN/ni
where N denotes the number of all diseases in the dataset and ni is the number of diseases where symptom i appears